# Sharing same SQL server for a SP2010 and SP2013 farm. Viable?

Tags: migration, sql-server

We are planning to migrate SP2010 to SP2013. Due to we have no spare SQL server (we do have separated APP and WFE servers), I am planning to install SP2013 on existing SQL instance with different DB naming.

Is it viable? Anything I need to take care? Thanks.

edit: Sorry, I just aware that the SQL server have MaxDOP=1 setup. Do I need to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

As long as it can handle the load and is an appropriate version, then there should be no problems.

Comment: Sorry, I just aware that the SQL server have MaxDOP=1 setup. Do I need to remove it?

Comment: NOOOO, MaxDOP=1 was a requirement for SP2010, but not enforced. For SP2013 it's still a requirement and now it's also enforced